# Markdown parsing error, parsing ends in infinite loops

Tags: markdown

目录结构\nPROJECT_Result\n__________Calculate\n__________TempFile\n__________tmpForCompareFile TransFile\n__________datFile\n__________20140417212430_Heat\n__________Macro\n__________Heat\n__________force\n__________res\n__________TecolotFile\n__________20140417212430_Heat\n__________force\n__________res

The above text will result a markdown parsing error if you parsed through https://github.com/chjj/marked

I can't figure out which part is illegal token in original text. Can you please help?

Thank you!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to represent with this input?

Comment: It is supposed to be a project directory structure, but this parser interprets "_" into <em> tag, resulting halt.

Comment: I still don't understand. What are the `_` characters supposed to be? Are they part of the file / directory names? Why not just use a nested list to represent a directory structure?